# Is the function $f(x,y) = \log(1+\sqrt{|xy|})$ differentiable at $\vec{0}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find out if the function $f(x,y) = \log(1+\sqrt{|xy|})$ differentiable at $\vec{0}$. What I've figured out so far is the following. 
Firstly, $f(0,0) = 0$, and also the partial derivatives $D_1f(0,0) = D_2f(0,0) = 0$. Thus, if it is differentiable, then the following has to hold: 
$$
f(\vec{0}) = [0,0]\vec{h} + o(\|h\|), 
$$
that is, 
$$
\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} \frac{f(x,y)}{\|\vec{x}\|} = 0. 
$$
We need to check whether this holds or not. So I'm now trying to determine the limit
$$
\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} \frac{\log(1+\sqrt{|xy|})}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0
$$
I have thought about using the fact that $\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \ldots$ to get an expansion 
$$
\log(1+\sqrt{|xy|}) = \sqrt{|xy|} - \frac{|xy|}{2} + O(|xy|^3). 
$$
That gives 
$$
\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} \frac{f(x,y)}{\|\vec{x}\|} = 
\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} \frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\|\vec{x}\|} - \lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} \frac{|xy|}{2\|\vec{x}\|} + \lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} \frac{O(|xy|^3)}{\|\vec{x}\|}. 
$$
For the second term, I have 
$$
\frac{|xy|}{2\|\vec{x}\|} = \frac{|x||y|}{2\|\vec{x}\|} \leq \frac{\|x\|^2}{2\|\vec{x}\|} = \frac{\|x\|}{2} \to 0 \textrm{ as } \vec{x} \to 0
$$
For the third term  I have 
$$
\frac{O(|xy|^3)}{\|\vec{x}\|} \leq C \cdot \frac{|x|^3|y|^3}{\|\vec{x}\|}
\leq C \cdot \frac{\|\vec{x}\|^6}{\|\vec{x}\|} = C \cdot \|\vec{x}\|^5 \to 0 \textrm{ as } \vec{x} \to 0. 
$$
For the first term, I get only as far as: 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\|\vec{x}\|} \leq \frac{\sqrt{\|\vec{x}\|^2}}{\|\vec{x}\|} = 1. 
$$

Two questions:

1) Is what I've done so far correct and in the right direction to solve the problem?

2) If so, how to proceed from where I'm stuck?

Other approaches are also appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{\log(1+\sqrt{|xy|})}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{\log\left(1+\sqrt{|xy|}\right)}{\sqrt{|xy|}}\to N.E.$$

indeed

- $\frac{\log\left(1+\sqrt{|xy|}\right)}{\sqrt{|xy|}}\to 1$

but

- for $x=0\implies \frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$
- for $x=y=t\to 0^+\implies \frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{|t^2|}}{\sqrt{t^2+t^2}}=\frac{|t|}{t\sqrt 2}\to \frac1{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: Thanks. Does N.E. mean that the limit does not exist? If so, how to formally prove that the limit $\frac{\log(1+\sqrt{|xy|})}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ doesn't exist? 
Also this means that $f$ is not differentiable at $\vec{0}$ right?

Comment: @Sigurd Yes by definition since $\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} \frac{f(x,y)}{\|\vec{x}\|} \neq 0$ $f$ is not dfferentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!